# How to specify a reference path to an SDK in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, sdk

I'm having a problem in Visual Studio 2019 when I try to run my Unity build on my HoloLens because every time I try, I get met with the following error messages:

"Could not find SDK "WindowsTeam, Version= 10.0.18362.0"

"Could not find SDK "WindowsDesktop, Version= 10.0.18362.0"

"Could not find SDK "WindowsMobile, Version= 10.0.18362.0"

"Could not find SDK "WindowsMobile, Version= 10.0.18362.0" (it repeats)

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruykX.png)

The SDK is definitely installed. I checked it in the Visual Studio 2019 installer and it's definitely there.

[Speculation]
The only thing I can think of that might be causing problems is that my Windows installation is on my C: drive, which is an SSD. The SDKs, Visual Studio, just about all my programs are installed to my D: drive instead. Could that be causing a problem? [/Speculation]

I tried manually reinstalling the SDK to make sure it was correctly installed:

[Screenshot of installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eecjd.png)

Anyway I was checking through the project in Visual Studio and I noticed that the references for the Windows Desktop/Mobile/Team components don't have a path specified, the field is just blank.

[Screenshot of the Solution Explorer/Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s51Mn.png)

The field to specify a path is locked and no matter what I do, I can't seem to change it at all. Is it possible to manually specify the path to the SDK directory? If not, is there an alternative way to fix this?

Thank you for your time and I hope you have a pleasant week,

Jen

Comment: Based on the errors you do not have the Windows SDK nor Visual C++ 2015 installed on your system (on the correct drive)

Comment: The part about Visual Studio C++ 2015 confuses me a little because I'm not using VS 2015, and this is a C# build from Unity. I'm not entirely sure why it's looking for that.

The SDK is definitely there, is there a way for me to specify the directory of it? I have a feeling that Visual Studio is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: The project you are attempting to compile requires the `Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for UWP applications` which you don't have installed (or it's installed in a location Visual Studio is unware of).  The solution to both the SDK and Visual C++ problem is to install them in their default directory instead of their current directory.  You can change the location where Visual Studio looks by modifying the project properties.

Comment: What SDKs are listed in the project's Properties under *General > Windows SDK Version*? Set yours if it's available and not already set.

Comment: It's set to Windows 10, version 1903, (10;0; Build 18362). I tried changing it to a different version but got the same error. I've checked in the Visual Studio installer and it's got the SDKs installed so I don't know why it can't locate them.

Comment: Okay so I don't know why this worked. I was digging through the unity forums and someone suggested deleting the references to the missing SDK components so I tried it and now it works. I'm now able to deploy my app to the hololens and it runs just fine.